# Why can't I edit a post with pending/suggested edits even though I have enough rep?

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits

If a post has a pending edit (like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20362539/problems-with-if-and-else-if-statements-everything-seems-like-its-correct did for a bit) then it gets stuck in the review queue, requiring multiple approvals.

However, if it didn't have that pending edit, I could simply edit it and save it without any review/approval process.

So, why I can't I make edits to a post with pending edits and just save them?  Or conversely, if I have enough rep to edit without review, why shouldn't I be able to approve edits myself?

Comment: You mean you're locked out of the Improve option?

Comment: If I'm reading a post that has an edit and click "edit" I cannot edit the post, nor do I get an Improve option.

Comment: @Joe so you don't see [this button](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Ab570.png) when you are looking at the suggested edit?

Comment: You approved the edit, thus you "lost" the chance to Improve. In such case just wait until the edit is approved or rejected, on Stack Overflow it's usually taking few minutes.